# How to set up and use j2objc

Tags: ios, android-studio, j2objc

I would like to start off by saying that I am a novice programmer. I have only learned Java and Android studio, and I know very little about cmd prompts and that sort of thing. I recently found j2objc which can roughly translate my java code to objective c, and hopefully make it easier for me to transfer my app to ios. I also know there is a gradle version. For some reason, there is no "tutorial" on youtube about setting up any type of j2objc. My Android studio project is on my Windows 8 desktop and my IOS xcode app is on a VM running IOS 10.13. Can anyone help me get this working? (I may need you to explain things to me like I'm 5).

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry, but as the project lead for j2objc, I don't recommend you use it. j2objc has more benefit as the amount of shared client-side grows, so smaller apps go through a lot of pain for very little benefit. Our most successful client apps tend to be huge (think Gmail, or the Google Docs apps), written by large teams of engineers.

What I encourage is that you initially focus on sharing code on the server-side, with your apps providing the user interface but doing very little calculation on the client. If profiling your app shows it is slow due to network accesses, then you might consider caching or some other local code. If you keep all the interesting/changing features on the server-side, then small, lightweight clients require much less work even if they are rewritten for each new platform your team supports.